# How to convert type multipart.File to *os.File in Golang

Tags: go, cloudflare

I am trying to upload video to CloudFlare, but in docs they use os.Open but in my situation user uploads file via html form

Golang CloudFlare Docs: https://developers.cloudflare.com/stream/getting-started/uploading-golang/

```
file, err := c.FormFile("file")
if err != nil {
    log.Errorf("get file error: %s", err)
    return c.JSONStatus(http.StatusBadRequest)
}

sourceFile, err := file.Open()
if err != nil {
    log.Errorf("open file error: %s", err)
    return c.JSONStatus(http.StatusInternalServerError)
}

headers := make(http.Header)
headers.Add("X-Auth-Email", "***")
headers.Add("X-Auth-Key", "***")

config := &tus.Config{
    ChunkSize:           5 * 1024 * 1024, // Cloudflare Stream requires a minimum chunk size of 5MB.
    Resume:              false,
    OverridePatchMethod: false,
    Store:               nil,
    Header:              headers,
}

client, _ := tus.NewClient("https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/"+ accountID +"/media", config)

upload, _ := tus.NewUploadFromFile(sourceFile)

uploader, _ := client.CreateUpload(upload)

uploader.Upload()
```

Comment: `f` is undefined in your quoted code, and `sourceFile` is unused.. It's unlikely that `NewUploadFromFile` actually requires an `os.File`; any `io.Reader` is probably fine (check the documentation for `NewUploadFromFile` in the CloudFlare SDK docs). Just pass the `file` you got back from `formFile`.

Comment: Yes, there are several variables that are undefined (I have cut some code and forget to change it here). But if I pass file it does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually related to the [`go-tus` client](https://github.com/eventials/go-tus).

Cloudflare's example creates a `tus.Upload` from an `*os.File`, but rather than trying to "convert" your `multipart.File` to an `*os.File`, I would consider the other functions `go-tus` provides for getting a `tus.Upload`.

Looking at the [`docs`](https://godoc.org/github.com/eventials/go-tus), you should consider these two:

- `func NewUpload(reader io.Reader, size int64, metadata Metadata, fingerprint string) *Upload`
- `func NewUploadFromBytes(b []byte) *Upload`

Considering `multipart.File` implements the `io.Reader` interface, you can go with both of these. Which is best depends on your use case, but if the files being uploaded have a size of more than several tens of KB's, you should really `NewUpload`. `NewUploadFromBytes` forces you to read the entire file into memory first.

In case you need some inspiration for what the `size`, `metadata` and `fingerprint` arguments should contain, look at the [implementation of `NewUploadFromFile`](https://github.com/eventials/go-tus/blob/master/upload.go#L60).